# Reducing NEON vector with variable amounts of bits in each element into a single 32-bit value (concatenate variable-length bitfields)

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, simd, arm64, neon

I have the output of some computation which is in the form of two NEON `uint8x16_t` SIMD registers, one which contains some significant information in the lower `N` bits of each element, and a second register in which each element contains the value of `N` for each corresponding element in the other register. The remaining `8-N` bits in the first register are zeroed, and the sum of N across the entire vector can also be guaranteed to be `<= 32`.

What I need to do is to take these bits and concatenate them into a single register. I can make changes to the code producing these results and have them store the bits in the upper `N` bits instead of the lower `N`, and I can also reverse the order of the elements in the register.

The only hard restriction that can't be potentially worked around here is that there cannot be any padding bits between the concatenated bits, and order of concatenation must be the same for any values in either register.

The naive solution to this is of course to simply iterate over each element and accumulate:

```
uint32_t bit_reduce_naive(uint8x16_t bits, uint8x16_t bit_counts)
{
    uint32_t result = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != 16; ++i)
    {
        result <<= bit_counts[i];
        result |= bits[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

After this, my next attempt was to try a more SIMD approach and iteratively shift the upper bits by the count of the lower bits, and then or the upper and lower halves together to merge them into a new vector with half the elements (this is the u8 -> u16 step, the others are the same but with wider element sizes):

```
inline std::pair<uint16x8_t, uint16x8_t> reduce_step_u8(uint8x16_t bits, uint8x16_t bit_counts)
{
    const uint16x8_t expanded_count_lower = vmovl_u8(vget_low_u8(bit_counts));
    const uint16x8_t expanded_bits_lower  = vmovl_u8(vget_low_u8(bits));
    const uint16x8_t expanded_bits_higher = vmovl_high_u8(bits);
    return std::pair
    {
        vorrq_u16(expanded_bits_lower, vshlq_u16(expanded_bits_higher, expanded_count_lower)),
        vaddl_u8( vget_low_u8(bit_counts), vget_high_u8(bit_counts)),
    };
}
```

These can then be chained together to reduce the input to two uint64_t values which can be delt with in normal integer registers and returned:

```
uint32_t bit_reduce_better(uint8x16_t bits, uint8x16_t bit_counts)
{
    const auto [bits_u16, counts_u16] = reduce_step_u8(bits, bit_counts);
    const auto [bits_u32, counts_u32] = reduce_step_u16(bits_u16, counts_u16);
    const auto [bits_u64, counts_u64] = reduce_step_u32(bits_u32, counts_u32);

    const uint64_t low_bits  = vget_low_u64(bits_u64)[0];
    const uint64_t high_bits = vget_low_u64(bits_u64)[0];
    const uint64_t low_bits_count = vget_high_u64(counts_u64)[0];

    return static_cast<uint32_t>(low_bits | (high_bits << low_bits_count));
}
```

Note that this solution doesn't concatenate the bits in the same order as they appear in the vector but that isn't a hard requirement for this algorithm (it would simplify things when dealing with the code that the return value is used by but I'll have to modify it regardless).

At this point the solution is sufficiently fast and compact for the purposes I need it for but I thought it might be worth asking in case anyone has a better solution, since a faster version if one exists wouldn't go unappreciated

Comment: You should remove the `C` language tag.  The C language doesn't have `static_cast` and `std::pair`.  The C and C++ languages are distinct.

Comment: Just to confirm the tags, this is 32-bit [arm], not 64-bit [arm64] aka AArch64 with ASIMD?

Comment: Ah, didn't realise arm64 had a separate tag. Post updated with correct tags, although there's not really anything behind the theory of this question that I think isn't also applicable to 32 bit arm's neon, other than the fact that the vector size would be 8x8 rather that 8x16

Comment: ARM NEON has 128-bit `q` registers, the difference is that there are 64-bit `d` registers for *both* halves of each `q` reg, so some kinds of horizontal stuff is easier since it takes zero instructions to "unpack" a vector to two 64-bit halves.  Unless compilers do a bad job with intrinsics, which is common.

Comment: If you had SVE2 BITPERM, you could do something to turn the counts into bitmasks (e.g. `(1<<N) - 1` on 8-bit elements) and use `bext` to extract the corresponding bits into the bottom of 64-bit elements, leaving just one more reduction step.  But with NEON, yeah you'll want to use the counts.  Perhaps a magic multiplier (perhaps `(1<<N0) | (1<<N1) | ...`?) can do something to line up bitfields into the right position in the high half of a product, especially if the `N` values are always small enough.  Or shift the even elements left by 8-N so their bits are contiguous with the odd elements?

Comment: Or can we use shift-right-and-insert (with 16-bit element size *without* unpacking the data) with the same vector as both data inputs, and counts like `8-N[i-1]` (the N for the high half of each pair of 8-bit elements) to collapse the gap between the low and high bitfields within each 16-bit element.  Calculating the N values for the next step would require some horizontal pairwise addition I think, but ASIMD has that, and unlike x86 SSE3 it's efficient.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems `sri` is only available with an immediate count that applies to all elements, so I guess just a chain of `ushl` instructions.  (https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0596/2021-12/SIMD-FP-Instructions/USHL--Unsigned-Shift-Left--register--) There is no `ushr` with a register count, but negative counts shift right.  So we can move bits left and right to meet in the middle of 16-bit, then 32-bit, then 64-bit elements.  (And even to the boundary between 64-bit halves, if useful). Making useful count vectors might be the hard part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the method suggested by [@Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) of selectively shifting the lower of each pair of elements so that each pair of elements are effectively concatenated in the centre of each 2-element pair at each step and using pairwise addition, I was able to marginally improve upon the speed of my original code, while also making it concatenate the bits in vector order.

The act of then manipulating the offsets so that in the next step the lower elements would be shifted left and the upper elements right so that they would again meet in the middle ended up being more expensive than simply negating the original lower pair's offset and shifting the concatenated bits right to reset them for the next step. I was fairly confused attempting to work that process out so there may be room for improvement in that direction.

Regardless, the improved method is very slightly faster (~0.2ns faster in microbenchmarks on an Apple M2) but takes an extra 2 instructions in the generated assembly. It does also have the advantage of concatenating the bits in order, which the original method does not.

Improved per-step code below, the main reduce method is the same:

```
inline std::pair<uint16x8_t, uint16x8_t> reduce_step_u8(uint8x16_t bits, uint8x16_t bit_counts)
{
    const uint8x16_t mask = vzip1q_u8(vdupq_n_u8(0xFF), vdupq_n_u8(0x00));
    const uint8x16_t shift = vdupq_n_u8(8) - bit_counts;
    //the only bits that matter for the shift is the sign bit and the
    //3 least significant bits, so the fact that the upper 8 bits of each
    //16 bit shift value are non-zero does not matter
    const int16x8_t  reverse_shift = vdupq_n_s16(0) - vreinterpretq_u8_s16(shift);

    const uint8x16_t shifted_bits = vshlq_u8(bits, vandq_u8(shift, mask));
    
    return std::pair
    {
        vshlq_u16(vreinterpretq_u8_u16(shifted_bits), reverse_shift),
        vpaddlq_u8(bit_counts),
    };
}
```

Comment: Does `vzip1q_u8` optimize away with constant args?  I guess probably yes with Clang and hopefully GCC, but you could still write it as a 16-bit broadcast of `0x00FF` if you don't mind assuming little-endian.  I guess you'd then need a reinterpret since NEON/ASIMD intrinsics use different types for each integer vector arrangement.

Comment: Definitely yes with clang, I didn't test with GCC but hopefully it should. In all three iterations it's replaced by either a constant embedded in the instruction or replaced by an entirely different bit manipulation instruction. A 16 bit broadcast (or 32 or 64 for the other iterations) would of course also work, but the zip seemed to me like it more clearly communicated the idea of the mask covering every other element so it's mostly for expressiveness

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm used to programming for SSE/AVX intrinsics where there aren't different types for different element sizes, where I'd write `__m128i evenmask = _mm_set1_epi16(0x00FF)`, with the two leading zeros indicating the placeholder spot.  There are some compilers for x86 (notably MSVC) that take intrinsics fairly literally and probably would emit a run-time `punpcklbw` if you wrote `_mm_unpacklo_epi8`, or a shift if you wrote `_mm_srli_epi16(v, 8)`.  (Which is actually not a terrible way to materialize that constant; x86 doesn't have vector-immediates like ARM, but all-ones is pcmpeqd)